# Icons in two columns in Inkscape toolbars, is it possible?

Tags: inkscape, linux

I'm using Inkscape on a laptop that has a vertical resolution of 800px.

The main toolbar, the one that by default is docked on the left part of the screen, has more icons than could be fitted on the available space, and to access them all, I have to click on the bottom arrow-shaped button.

[image]

Is it possible to arrange those icons in two columns, so that they are always visible? I've tried to navigate through the program settings, but I can't find if and how is possible to do so.

If it is relevant, I'm using openSUSE Linux.

Comment: Changing the order of them, if possible, would be very useful too, since I don't use some of them and others rarely.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is currently possible. There's been a bug report since 2009 about this issue...

https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/414372

I'm not sure if it'll help your workflow, but you can make the icons slightly smaller, which may display one or two more perhaps. If you look in **Edit / Preferences / Interface**, you can change icon size there (you need to restart afterwards).

[image: smaller icons in Inkscape]

EDIT: forgot to add, all of the tools in the left-hand toolbox can be accessed with keyboard shortcuts (if you hover over them, it shows the shortcut). Often it's simply quicker to memorise the ones you use most and simply use the keyboard instead of clicking.

Comment: Thank you, by setting them to "smaller" and using full screen, I've gained access to almost all of them.